# Can somebody help me with bootstrap4 carousel-indicators

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have added text previous and next instead of regular carousel-indicators. i was able to center align the text horizontally but vertically it is not centered.

Below are the carousel-indicators html and styles:

```
.carousel-indicators {
   top: 400px;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
   position: relative;
   left: 20px;
   width: 208px;
   height: 56px;
   border-radius: 12px;
   background-color: var(--dark-blue);
   margin-right: 2em;
   text-indent: unset;
   color: var(--white-bg);
   font-size: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
   background-color: var(--dark-blue);
}

<ol class="carousel-indicators text-uppercase text-center">
   <li data-target="#mycarouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active" > Previous </li>
   <li data-target="#mycarouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1">Next</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: <ol class="carousel-indicators text-uppercase text-center">
            <li
              data-target="#mycarouselIndicators"
              data-slide-to="0"
              class="active"
            >
              Previous
            </li>
            <li data-target="#mycarouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1">Next</li>
          </ol>

Comment: .carousel-indicators {
    top: 400px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    width: 208px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
    margin-right: 2em;
    text-indent: unset;
    color: var(--white-bg);
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: var(--dark-blue);
}

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="bottom: 50%;"` to your `<ol>` and it should work as expected.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators text-uppercase text-center" style="bottom: 50%;">
   <li data-target="#mycarouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active" > Previous </li>
   <li data-target="#mycarouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1">Next</li>
</ol>
```